# Can someone clone my GitHub Pages repo?

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm new to GitHub Pages and still trying to wrap my head around the concept.

If I publish a blog (using Jekyll) with GutHub Pages, can someone else just come in and clone my entire repo, thereby getting all my content, my theme (which I purchased), and all my images, etc.?

Or, if my blog is published with GitHub Pages, does GitHub by default prevent people from performing that basic GitHib function (i.e. cloning a repository).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, if you publish articles, images and CSS on the web, whether or not you use github pages, anybody can download them: that's a requirement to be able to read the articles, see the images, and enjoy the theme.

Comment: Anything in GitHub is a repository, and anyone can clone that. But, of course, everything is downloadable on the web. That's literally how it's designed.

Comment: True, and thank you for your responses. I guess the difference is that when you're downloading a website directly, you're downloading the rendered HTML and you wouldn't have access  to all the config files or layouts with their accompanying logic (for loops, conditional statements, and such) that you would get from cloning a repo.

Comment: May I refine the question?  Can someone download or fork the blog with just a single button-click?  (e.g. by clicking a "Download zip" button).  Granted that everything on the web is more or less downloadable, that doesn't mean it's a good idea to give users a super-simple way to abscond with years of content that is not public domain.  It's like leaving your front door wide open instead of merely unlocked. Not everyone can write a `wget` command. This is a reasonable consideration in deciding on a blog platform.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to host a website on GitHub Pages without providing users access to your "raw content" and templates is by uploading "the generated site" to GitHub instead:

- Build your site locally by running **either of the following** in your terminal.:

  ```
  JEKYLL_ENV=production bundle exec jekyll build
  JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll build
  ```
- Setup the destination directory, `_site` as your git repo:

  ```
  cd _site
  git init
  git remote add origin https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-USERNAME.github.io.git
  ```
- Commit the generated site and push to your GitHub repo

  ```
  git add .
  git commit -m "Generated my site!"
  git push origin master
  ```

  If your repository isn't empty, the `git push` above will fail. Using the `--force` flag will **overwrite** your remote branch.

  ```
  git push origin master --force
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. This should have been obvious to me, but wasn't. Thank you!